# A integration question which bothers me

Tags: probability, integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

I want to integrate function $f(x,y)=1/\pi$ on the unit circle $C=\{x^2+y^2<1\}$, I will have:
$$\int\int_C f(x,y)dxdy=1$$
Now I just want to change variable and calculate this as:
$$z=x-y,w=y$$
then 
$$x=w+z,y=w,|\frac{\partial xy}{\partial wz}|=1$$
The region $x^2+y^2<1$ is mapped to $2w^2+2wz+z^2-1<0$ this is equivalent to

$$\frac{-z-\sqrt{2-z^2}}{2}<w<\frac{-z+\sqrt{2-z^2}}{2}$$
So I can rewrite the integration as:
$$\int\int_C f(x,y)dxdy=\int_{-1}^1\int_{\frac{-z-\sqrt{2-z^2}}{2}}^{\frac{-z+\sqrt{2-z^2}}{2}} \frac{1}{\pi}|\frac{\partial xy}{\partial wz}|dwdz$$
$$=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{\pi}\sqrt{2-z^2}dz=1+\frac{\pi}{2}\neq 1$$

So where in my calculation is wrong? Is it a small calculation mistake or there is substantial thing I'm missing?

Comment: Try changing variables to polar coordinates. @RushengZhang

Comment: Your range of $z$ is not correct. It probably should lie in $[-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}]$. Also, I cannot think of a reason for you to use such a wired way of changing variables. You have so many choices such as polar coordinates or just simply use $-\sqrt{1-y^2}\leq x\leq\sqrt{1-y^2}$.

Comment: @user52919: I think you are missing the point here. The OP already knows how to find the answer (see the first equation in the post!), and just out of curiosity wants to see if the change-of-variables formula gives a result which is consistent with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes: You forgot the factor $1/\pi$ in the very last step, and (more seriously) you must have $\displaystyle \int_{-\sqrt2}^{\sqrt2} (\cdots) \, dz$, since that's how far the new region of integration (an ellipse) extends in the $z$ direction.

Comment: Thank you...... I actually checked this for a long time.